# AFNetworking UIImage NSURL

Tags: ios, uiimageview, afnetworking, nsurl

I use AFNetworking to get beer details from my rails api, and I want to show an image from a url that is returned.

Example API response

```
    description = "Super tasty";
    id = 3;
    "label_url" = "/system/beers/labels/000/000/003/medium/Pliny.png?1363034728";
    "location_id" = 2;
    name = "Pliny The Elder";
    price = "3.5";
    style = IPA;
```

The label_url is the url for the image, which I'm trying to display in the BeerDetailViewController. Here is what I've tried so far, which builds with no errors but no image displays.

```
BeerDetailViewController.m

#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFImageRequestOperation.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    beerLabel.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                              [NSURL URLWithString: beer_label]]];
```

Any ideas why it's not working? I can display the url in this view with something like `beerLabel.text = beer_label` so I know it's coming through and read to be used, just not sure why it isn't displaying an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/system/beers/labels/000/000/003/medium/Pliny.png?1363034728
```

is not a valid URL. **Seriously, how would poor `NSURL` and `NSData` know what host are you looking for?** You need to construct a proper URL string using the host and this *path*.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is only the path portion of a URL. You want to resolve this against the correct base URL. So let's say your server is `example.com`. To resolve it:

```
NSURL *base = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSURL *resolved = [NSURL URLWithString:beer_label relativeToURL:base];
```